# Delete Array Row With .contextMenu

Tags: macos, swiftui

I want to delete a row from `keydata` if a user uses the .contextMenu { }, here "Hello World löschen".

```
@State private var keyData = [
    ListView("1", "Hello", "World"),
    ListView("2", "Bye", "Wold")
]
```

[image]

```
ForEach($keyData) { $i in
    NavigationLink()) {
        //
    }
    .contextMenu {
        Button { } // ?
        label: {
            Text(i.firstName) +
            Text(" ") +
            Text(i.lastName) +
            Text(" löschen")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the index to delete the item you want to remove (efficiently). Change your `ForEach`:

```
ForEach(Array(keyData.enumerated()), id: \.element) { (index, element) in
    NavigationLink("test", destination: Text("test"))
    .contextMenu {
        Button {
            keyData.remove(at: index)
        } label: {
            Text(element.firstName) +
            Text(" ") +
            Text(element.lastName) +
            Text(" löschen")
        }
    }
}
```

And you can replace any `$i` bindings with `$keyData[index]`.